# What is database name attribute in Oracle connection string for .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, connection-string

I am using Oracle.EntityFrameWork package and with below connection string in my dbContext.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options){
options.UseOracle(@"Data Source=sampleip:port/serviceName;User Id=sample; Password=sample;")
}
```

It works but I need specify database name. I tried "Initial Catalog" but it doesn't work.

Comment: You wanna specify database name in your connection string?

Comment: I am not sure if i get your point, Why don't you put the database name in `{serviceName}` part?